# Need ideas for a Decision Tree

Tags: sql, oracle, scripting

Not sure how to ask this as I can not recall the term that would best describe what I want but I'll give it a shot.

I need an mechanism whereby one could so something like this:  Given A and desiring B, what steps would be needed to get me there.

This is going to be used in the Oracle db realm where a data point is known and another is needed but the path from one to the other is not, so the goal is to have this mechanism provide the mapping.  You know, select  from  and then... etc.

Does this make sense?  Apparently not.  Let me try an example....

Organization with multiple tables in a db where similar data appears in different tables but often with different field/column names.

I want to be able to answer this question...

I have data value "A" and I need data value "B".  The answer would be something like...

Select * from  where ....
then, 
Select * from  where ...
then, 
Select * from

The issue again is, that data exists in multiple tables but to get what I want I need to do multiple selects using different fields (or joins, etc).

What I'm looking for basically is a tool that would provide the mapping (using SQL) to get what I want.

Comment: No, this does not make sense.  Sample data and desired results often help.

Comment: I've edited my question for clarity.

Comment: @dnbush Are you trying to find tables that are related through foreign keys?  So if A is a parent of B, and B is a parent of C, you want to be able to create a graph that includes A, B, and C?

Comment: @JonHeller, I'm not specifically thinking of keys.  What we have are multiple tables, many with the same data but with dissimilar field names.  What I'm looking for is a mechanism that will allow me to input the data that I have, not the specific value but the type, like account number, and also what I'm looking for, like Last name, and this mechanism will tell me what tables I need to select from or what joins I need to construct to get what I want.

Comment: Sounds like you need the DWIM key!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally our database schemas are self-explanatory.  Using thoughtful table and column names goes a long way to making a schema more usable.  Have a good development process that enables refactoring helps us keep our schemas sane.

When names aren't good enough, we can use COMMENTs on tables and columns to help explain what they mean.  Many IDEs automatically retrieve comments and display them in result grids.  Foreign key and check constraints can also be used to help us understand relationships in our data.

The data dictionary contains information about our schemas that can be used to help us reason about our objects.  For example:

```
select * from dba_tab_cols;
select * from dba_tab_comments;
select * from dba_col_comments;
select * from dba_constraints;
```

Some organizations use a modeling tool to create diagrams of tables and columns, and contain the "logical" names.  In my experience those sources are not kept in sync with the database and are not helpful.

Finally, if the above is not sufficient, we can create a logical layer of views on top of our tables.  SQL is a high-level, English-like language, and is a good way to describe the relationships between objects.

If you're using one of those systems where columns are given names like C00, C01, C02, and not allowed to create views, I've never seen a good solution to that problem.  Everyone just suffers, and hopefully learns their lesson and creates a more meaningful schema next time.